# Tool to monitor new releases of open-source software

Tags: monitoring, open-source

I'm looking for an open-source tool that is used to monitor releases of new versions of open-source software and is built using a plug-in architecture (one plug-in for each app that must be monitored).

This is a generic task, at least for package maintainers, so I believe there are such tools and I won't have to write something up myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [created a google account](https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount?service=reader) and added these tools' news feeds to Google Reader which displays RSS for me. For projects that does not have any RSS - you can create RSS feeds for project news in [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/).

Also seek for tools that create RSS feed entries when page contents change.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

These guys have what you need.

> The Ohloh API is a free, REST-based
>   programming interface to the Ohloh
>   open source directory. You can use the
>   Ohloh API to create your own
>   applications and web services based on
>   Ohloh data.

[ohloh.net](http://ohloh.net)